# Python Regex split (A)(B)(C)(D) into new lines

Tags: python, regex

I write a regex to separate choices into new lines,

```
(?P<qn>^\d+)\s*?\.(?P<qt>.*?)\s*?(?P<A>A\s*?\..*?)\n*?(?P<B>B\s*?\..*?)\n*?(?P<C>C\s*?\..*?)\n*?(?P<D>D\s*?\..*?)\n*(?=\Z)
```

See https://www.regex101.com/r/hP0nX4/2

```
14.下列牙齒外傷，何者最易發生牙髓壞死？

A.震盪（concussion） 
B.半脫臼（subluxation） 
C.凸出性脫位（extrusive luxation） 
D.內縮性脫位（intrusive luxation）

15  .藥物在正常使用下，何種藥品對
Enterococcus faecalis 的殺菌效果通常最快？
A.2.5％次氯酸鈉（NaOCl） B.0.5％chlorhexidine C.2％iodine／4％potassium iodide D.氫氧化鈣（Ca(OH)2）

16  .有關根管治療時使用EDTA移除塗抹層（smear      layer）之敘述，下列何者錯誤？
A.臨床上常使用的EDTA濃度為27％ B.其作用為EDTA與牙本質碎屑中的鈣離子螯合（chelating），來幫助移除塗抹層 C.EDTA可深入牙本質小管約50µm D.EDTA與次氯酸鈉（NaOCl）併用可移除塗抹層
```

The question No. 14 is well formatted, No.15 & 16 are not.

My regex only match one question, how can I make it to match all questions.
And separate all choices into new line?

---

My expected output is:

```
14.下列牙齒外傷，何者最易發生牙髓壞死？

A.震盪（concussion） 
B.半脫臼（subluxation） 
C.凸出性脫位（extrusive luxation） 
D.內縮性脫位（intrusive luxation）

15  .藥物在正常使用下，何種藥品對
Enterococcus faecalis 的殺菌效果通常最快？
A.2.5％次氯酸鈉（NaOCl） 
B.0.5％chlorhexidine 
C.2％iodine／4％potassium iodide 
D.氫氧化鈣（Ca(OH)2）

16  .有關根管治療時使用EDTA移除塗抹層（smear      layer）之敘述，下列何者錯誤？
A.臨床上常使用的EDTA濃度為27％ 
B.其作用為EDTA與牙本質碎屑中的鈣離子螯合（chelating），來幫助移除塗抹層
C.EDTA可深入牙本質小管約50µm 
D.EDTA與次氯酸鈉（NaOCl）併用可移除塗抹層
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Hi, @AvinashRaj . My expected output is to put the choice A,B,C,D at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just repace the space which exists before `B` or `C` or `D` `.` with newline character.

```
re.sub(r'\s+(?=[BCD]\.)', '\n', s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nC1wN3/1)

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''14.下列牙齒外傷，何者最易發生牙髓壞死？

A.震盪（concussion） 
B.半脫臼（subluxation） 
C.凸出性脫位（extrusive luxation） 
D.內縮性脫位（intrusive luxation）

15  .藥物在正常使用下，何種藥品對
Enterococcus faecalis 的殺菌效果通常最快？
A.2.5％次氯酸鈉（NaOCl） B.0.5％chlorhexidine C.2％iodine／4％potassium iodide D.氫氧化鈣（Ca(OH)2）

16  .有關根管治療時使用EDTA移除塗抹層（smear      layer）之敘述，下列何者錯誤？
A.臨床上常使用的EDTA濃度為27％ B.其作用為EDTA與牙本質碎屑中的鈣離子螯合（chelating），來幫助移除塗抹層 C.EDTA可深入牙本質小管約50µm D.EDTA與次氯酸鈉（NaOCl）併用可移除塗抹層'''

>>> print(re.sub(r'\s+(?=[BCD]\.)', '\n', s))
14.下列牙齒外傷，何者最易發生牙髓壞死？

A.震盪（concussion）
B.半脫臼（subluxation）
C.凸出性脫位（extrusive luxation）
D.內縮性脫位（intrusive luxation）

15  .藥物在正常使用下，何種藥品對
Enterococcus faecalis 的殺菌效果通常最快？
A.2.5％次氯酸鈉（NaOCl）
B.0.5％chlorhexidine
C.2％iodine／4％potassium iodide
D.氫氧化鈣（Ca(OH)2）

16  .有關根管治療時使用EDTA移除塗抹層（smear      layer）之敘述，下列何者錯誤？
A.臨床上常使用的EDTA濃度為27％
B.其作用為EDTA與牙本質碎屑中的鈣離子螯合（chelating），來幫助移除塗抹層
C.EDTA可深入牙本質小管約50µm
D.EDTA與次氯酸鈉（NaOCl）併用可移除塗抹層
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a newline before "Enterococcus" that is not matched by `.` You can add the modifier `s` to make `.` also match newlines.

Note that the newline will still be in the result though.